# Unirest async request preventing the JVM from exiting

Tags: java, asynchronous, jvm, unirest

I'm trying to use asynchronous callbacks via unirest in Java. However, after switching from synchronous to asynchronous requests, the JVM doesn't seem to exit. I'm not sure what the thread dump is means either.

I'm compiling & running this on JDK 1.8.0_25 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 -

```
00:16 $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here is the code -

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.async.Callback;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import com.mashape.unirest.request.GetRequest;

public class SampleTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        GetRequest reqfuture;
        reqfuture = Unirest.get("http://www.google.com");

        reqfuture.asStringAsync(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse<String> httpResponse) {
                System.err.println("Completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                System.err.println("Failed");

            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                System.err.println("Cancelled");

            }
        });
        System.out.print("Exiting...");
    }
}
```

Here is the program output -

```
Starting...
Exiting...Completed
2014-12-20 00:41:30
```

Here is the thread dump -

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #23 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcac85e000 nid=0x1903 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"I/O dispatcher 8" #22 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcac08b000 nid=0x7103 runnable [0x000000012d9c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7b80> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7b70> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7a50> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 7" #21 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab998000 nid=0x6f03 runnable [0x000000012d8c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7810> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7800> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc76e0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 6" #20 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcaf017000 nid=0x6d03 runnable [0x000000012d7bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc74a0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7490> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7370> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 5" #19 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcaf016000 nid=0x6b03 runnable [0x000000012d6bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7130> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7120> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc7000> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 4" #18 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab94c800 nid=0x6903 runnable [0x000000012d5b9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6dc0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6db0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6c90> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 3" #17 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab94b000 nid=0x6703 runnable [0x000000012d4b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6a50> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6a40> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6920> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 2" #16 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcaf015800 nid=0x6503 runnable [0x000000012d3b3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc66e0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc66d0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc65b0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"I/O dispatcher 1" #15 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcac82a000 nid=0x6303 runnable [0x000000012d2b0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6370> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6360> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bfc6240> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-2" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae070800 nid=0x6103 in Object.wait() [0x000000012d1ad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076bee9e10> (a com.mashape.unirest.http.async.utils.AsyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.async.utils.AsyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread.run(AsyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread.java:22)
    - locked <0x000000076bee9e10> (a com.mashape.unirest.http.async.utils.AsyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread)

"pool-1-thread-1" #13 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae064800 nid=0x5f03 runnable [0x000000012d0aa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x000000076bc15568> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x000000076bc154e8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000076bc13bf0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:340)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.doExecute(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.access$000(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:38)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-1" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae94b800 nid=0x5d03 in Object.wait() [0x000000012cf97000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076bbb12f8> (a com.mashape.unirest.http.utils.SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.utils.SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread.run(SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread.java:22)
    - locked <0x000000076bbb12f8> (a com.mashape.unirest.http.utils.SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae012000 nid=0x5b03 runnable [0x000000012cc0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000076b026110> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    - locked <0x000000076b026110> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcaf00a000 nid=0x5703 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae800000 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcac809000 nid=0x5303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab82c800 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab82b000 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab838000 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab812000 nid=0x3903 in Object.wait() [0x000000012c120000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076ab06280> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x000000076ab06280> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab05c800 nid=0x3703 in Object.wait() [0x000000012c01d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076ab05cf0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x000000076ab05cf0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab058000 nid=0x3503 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab80f800 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae000000 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab810000 nid=0x2903 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab810800 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab811000 nid=0x2d03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcac807800 nid=0x2f03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae001000 nid=0x3103 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcae001800 nid=0x3303 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fdcab840800 nid=0x5903 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 283

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 39323K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000770000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 60% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076d166e60,0x000000076eb00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f580000,0x000000076f580000,0x0000000770000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076eb00000,0x000000076eb00000,0x000000076f580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 9174K, capacity 9400K, committed 9728K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 1102K, capacity 1155K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
```

Any pointers to fix this would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `Unirest.shutdown();`

See [documentation](http://unirest.io/java.html)`

Comment: Shutdown is a good option. But, what I'm experiencing, is that Tomcat gives 30 sec to shutdown. When calling `Unirest.shutdown()` the `SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread` (one of the 3 services `shutdown` shuts down) will wait for 5 sec, then may wait for another 30 sec. Do you know how to: force a faster shutdown, or increase the 30 sec Tomcat allowed shutdown time (or war stop time)?

Comment: this link goes somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

We can see from the dump that there are two threads of `com.mashape.unirest.http.utils.SyncIdleConnectionMonitorThread` that are stuck (might be deadlock).

Most chances are that either the library that you're using is not releasing resources or there's a deadlock. An ugly workaround would be to use `System.exit()` as the last operation in `completed()` but personally I would rather find another (more stable) library that provides the same services.

There's also a chance that the issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're running the code from your IDE (IntelliJ). Try running the same code from command-line and see if you can reproduce.